# Can someone help me understand what these scripts mean?

Tags: script

Could someone explain what the commands i have in **bold** do? if possible. Thank you.

[Transaction URL www.blockchain.com/btc/tx](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d5660360c401e17e5f0f0fbcabc3c369002bf2a58a6eaeaf1d8242dd01da3f72)

Input Scripts-
ScriptSig: **PUSHDATA(71)**[3044022069f0c9da12ce7b002c68d25e4445191b149627987367fdec4e4b80e442379f3902202109994c46d8c6afd8e94542d07fa8a07da234f7537c4a1d639d2dcdd32f9c5b01] **PUSHDATA(33)**[03c26e5ff8c75d6272b2d9cd3a882c20315d440251deb79873b75b690d0b71f4cf]

Output Scripts-
**DUP HASH160 PUSHDATA**(20)[264cf7a09b68a436bafc4d7281743d7f1c721ded] **EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG
HASH160 PUSHDATA**(20)[72cf56ba8b7312ae658debf033d88e4370b9a8f5] **EQUAL**

Comment: Note that you have two separate output scripts merged together in your question. There are two outputs and therefore two output scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice [introduction to script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) and already another answer explaining what these *specific commands* do, but I will try to explain what these *scripts* actually do.

They implement a very standard bitcoin transaction called *pay-to-pubkey-hash transaction*.

The idea is roughly the following. Let's call this transaction `A`. To spend the output of transaction `A`, another transaction will be created and broadcasted, let's call it `B`. In order to verify the validity of transaction `B`, one should:

1. combine the input script of `B` with the output script of `A`,
2. execute the combined script and verify that it returns `True`.

In this type of transactions, transaction `B` should provide an input script that puts two elements to the stack: the signature `sig` of the transaction and a corresponding public key `pubKey`. Note how the input script of transaction `A` is also doing exactly that.

Then the output script of transaction `A` will do the following (in your question you actually provide two output scripts merged together, because there are two outputs, I will focus on the first one):

1. Duplicate `pubKey` on the stack;
2. Hash one `pubKey` from the stack and verify that it is equal to `264cf7a09b68a436bafc4d7281743d7f1c721ded`
3. Take `sig` and the  remaining `pubKey` from the stack and verify the validity of the signature.

Comment: 1st thank you. 2nd I think i understand what your saying. So basically for the balance to be spendable, another transaction has to take place to verify it spendable?

Comment: @gReigns roughly, yes, depending on what you mean by “spendable”. Transaction A dictates the conditions under which the balance (or rather UTXO is a better term) can be spend. But until transaction B appears and spends these outputs by providing the right signature, no one really knows if these conditions are possible to meet.

Answer (score 0):

- PUSHDATA(71): Pushes the next 71 bytes onto the top of stack
- PUSHDATA(33): Pushes the next 33 bytes onto the top of stack
- DUP: Pushes a duplicate of the top stack item onto the top of the stack
- HASH160: Pop the top stack item off of the stack, hash it using SHA256 then that hash with RIPEMD160, and push the resulting hash to the top of the stack
- PUSHDATA(20): Push the next 20 bytes onto the top of the stack
- EQUALVERIFY: Check that the top two stack items are equal. If they are, do nothing. If they are not, immediately fail execution
- CHECKSIG:Pop the top stack item and interpret it as a public key. Pop the next stack item and interpret it as a signature. Check that the signature verifies to that public key when the message that is signed is a modified version of the transaction containing the signature. If the signature is valid, push OP_TRUE to the top of the stack. If it is false, push OP_FALSE to the top of the stack.

A full description of all script opcodes and their actual byte values can be found [on the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script).

Comment: Can't believe that this was not a duplicate. I will add a link to a video in which I dissect a pay2pkh tx: https://youtu.be/1n4g3eYX1UI that should help to understand how these op codes work